# Разместить элемент с правой стороны в TableLayout

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. Есть следующая разметка:

`

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/background_head"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/cat_sled" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="@style/ThemeButtonHead"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:minWidth="90dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textColor="@color/ColorHeadTextButton"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</TableRow>
```

`

Я хочу сделать чтобы кнопка распалогалась с правой стороны, не как не выходит сделать. Буду благодарен за помощь.

**И еще один вопрос**

Я написал страницу с разметкой:
`

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:maxHeight="150dp"
    android:maxWidth="150dp"
    android:src="@drawable/cat" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Title1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/Title1Text"
    android:textColor="@color/Title1Color"
    android:textSize="23sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Title2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Title1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="@string/Title2Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonStart"
    style="@style/ThemeButtonTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Title2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/cat_sled"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    android:onClick="onClickSound"
    android:text="@string/BStart"
    android:textColor="@color/Button1TitleColor"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:width="100dp" />
```

`
Меня волнует вот что, будет ли нормально это отображаться на устройствах с разными размерами экрана.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов - добавляете между элементами спейсер (пустое пространство) с параметром `android:layout_weight="1"` - заполнять всю доступную незанятую площадь в контейнере, это раздвинет крайние элементы по углам, оставив им только необходимое пространство:

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/background_head"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/cat_sled" />

    <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="@style/ThemeButtonHead"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:minWidth="90dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textColor="@color/ColorHeadTextButton"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</TableRow>
```

PS: ImageView должен иметь размеры по ширине и высоте `wrap_content`, для `Button` `android:layout_gravity="right"` - совершенно лишнее.

По второй части вопроса. Вообще здесь правило: один вопрос - одна проблема, но на ваш второй вопрос можно ответить только так, что никто за вас не будет тестировать ваши разметки на разных устройствах - если физических устройств для тестов недостаточно в наличии, создавайте эмуляторы с разными разрешениями экрана - телефонов, планшетов, телевизоров и чего вам там еще надо и тестируйте.
Вся необходимая информация по поддержке устройств с разным разрешением в полной мере собрана [здесь](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)